# How to Add EventTrigger with SoundActions in code behind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

So I'm trying to create controls on the fly (RegularPolygon to be exact) and I want to add 2 PlaySoundActions to the controls as an EventTrigger based off of the Tap Event.  Currently I have the following code:

```
EventTrigger trigger = new EventTrigger();
PlaySoundAction correct = new PlaySoundAction();
PlaySoundAction incorrect = new PlaySoundAction();
correct.Source = new Uri("/Sounds/Correct.mp3");
correct.Volume = 0.5;
incorrect.Source = new Uri("/Sounds/Incorrect.mp3");
incorrect.Volume = 0.5;

trigger.Actions.Add(correct);   // this line doesn't work
trigger.Actions.Add(incorrect); // this also doesn't work
shape.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Each line has an error like

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media.PlaySoundAction' to
>   'System.Windows.TriggerAction'

I'm not entirely sure what to cast the PlaySoundAction object as.  I don't want to do this in XAML because I'm creating these controls on the fly.

I also tried creating a Style for RegularPolygon to have the EventTrigger with the PlaySoundAction(s), but setting the style of the control programmatically does not add this logic to the control.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="es:RegularPolygon" x:Key="Default">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <eim:PlaySoundAction Source="/Sounds/Incorrect.mp3" Volume="0.5" />
                        <eim:PlaySoundAction Source="/Sounds/Correct.mp3" Volume="0.5" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Is there a way to add an EventTrigger/PlaySoundAction in code behind or create a style that a control can inherit from that has an EventTrigger/PlaySoundAction?**

Comment: The documentation says Actions is a collection of BeginStoryboard objects, so maybe PlaySoundAction just doesn't qualify?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.actions(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to know that you are trying to use System.Windows.EventTrigger instead of System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger in your code. When I explicitly specified that - I got it to work:

```
System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger = 
    new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
trigger.EventName = "MouseLeftButtonDown";
PlaySoundAction correct = new PlaySoundAction();
correct.Source = new Uri("/Sample.wma", UriKind.Relative);
correct.Volume = 1.0;
trigger.Actions.Add(correct);
trigger.Attach(myTextBlock);
```

You need to make sure that your control can be tapped too - IsHitTestVisible can't be set to false and it needs to have a fill brush set. Not sure what your custom control does.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid
    x:Name="ContentPanel"
    Background="LightCoral"
    Tap="ContentPanel_Tap"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="12,0,12,0" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            Text="XAML Test">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger
                    EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <eim:PlaySoundAction
                        Source="/Balloon.wav"
                        Volume="1" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock
            Margin="0,100,0,0"
            x:Name="myTextBlock"
            Text="Coded Test" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to check that out once I get a chance.

Comment: This allows me to add the EventTrigger sure enough, but getting it to trigger seems to be another issue.

Comment: I put my solution here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1192076/PlaySoundActionTest.zip

Also adding the XAML to my answer.

Comment: This will get me where I'm going for now and I'll see if I can come up with a better question next round of updates.